# What is the most appropriate preposition in the following sentence?

Tags: prepositions

I had a tour of/in/to Norway. The sentence should mean I visited different places in the country.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, all three prepositions could be used. However, they can have different meanings.

---

I am going to slightly rephrase your sentence so that I can easily use all three prepositions. (Using **to** in your original sentence would be awkward at best.)

> I went on a tour **of** Norway.

This means that you went to Norway with the purpose of touring around the country. It's the most directly relevant of the prepositions.

> I went on a tour **in** Norway.

This means that at some point while you were in Norway, you went on a tour. It could have been a tour of a particular city, of a brewery, or of a textile mill. But it doesn't mean it was a tour of multiple places or of the country itself.

> I went on a tour **to** Norway.

This could mean that you went on a tour that resulted in your destination being Norway. It doesn't necessarily mean that your tour consisted of sites in Norway and nowhere else.

In informal dialogue, you can say that you want to book a tour **to** somewhere and mean it in the same sense as booking a tour **of** somewhere. It's no doubt used somewhat interchangeably because of its association with booking a ***trip*** **to** somewhere. But it wouldn't be as common as using **of**, and it can also be meant in the other sense.

---

> The sentence should mean I visited different places in the country.

In short, **of** is the most appropriate preposition for this meaning because its single interpretation most closely matches what you're looking for.

Comment: Whilst I am fully in agreement with your answer, it should also perhaps be clarified what is meant by "going on a tour" (which incidentally I agree is more idiomatic than "had a tour"). It suggests an organised tour, arranged by another party. If you travel under your own steam and select places to visit and stopover then you don't so much "go on a tour" as "go touring", or "tour"; e.g. "We toured Norway last summer".

Comment: @WS2 That would also bypass the issue of prepositions. ;)